# What rules do I need to remote desktop to a virtual machine where the host has iptables running?

Tags: linux, iptables, virtual-machines

I am attempting to remote desktop to a virtual Ubuntu install (headless on VirtualBox) that resides on a Linux host (Centos 6.6). I can reach it with no issue if I turn iptables off. I feel like I have tried every combination of PREROUTING and FORWARD on the internet to no avail.

My host is at 10.7.80.41. I can connect to the VM running on that host via 10.7.80.41:3389 from my Windows 7 machine and from a Linux machine on the same network - as long as iptables is off.

I set /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward to 1, and tried different variations of this basic setup:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -d 10.7.80.41 --dport 3389 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.7.80.41:3389
iptables -A FORWARD -j ACCEPT -p tcp --dport 3389
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 3389 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

...and I have run out of ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see no reason for you to make any kind of `PREROUTING DNAT` rule in your IPTables, since you are not accessing the private network address from the outside world. In fact, this `DNAT` rule might be the thing that breaks your setup.

Comment: You were correct. A simple INPUT/OUPUT for port 3389 and I was in like Flynn. Guess i overthought it.